# Mismatch during first run

Tags: 7, media, migrations

Migrating D7 to D7 in 2 subdirectories:

`/public_html/siteold/` with db=dbold
`/public_html/sitenew/` with db=dbnew

I am using the UI of migrate_d2d. In a first run, I migrated users, files and content type "news". "news" content was migrated tot content type "article" with the same properties

All seemed to work well, but results were incomplete

- The new uid did not match the old one
- Images were not transferred

I tried to change the field settings, to no avail.

After two days of trying, I have no idea of the cause of the mismatch.

How can I fix this?